# JQuery - Clickable table row, except last cell

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to user JQuery to make a table row clickable and redirect to a URL which is hidden in the first cell.
I've got an image in the last column of the table which should redirect to a different URL.

JQuery is as follows.

```
$(function () {
    $('#link-table td:first-child').hide();

    $('#link-table tr').hover(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    });

    $('#link-table tr').click(function () {
        location.href = $(this).find('td a').attr('href');
    });
});
```

Clicking the row works, clicking the image hyperlink in the last cell redirects to the same URL as clicking the row which isn't what I want.

I tried using this code for the click event

```
$('#link-table tr td:not(:last-child))').click(function () {
        location.href = $(this).find('td a').attr('href');
    });
```

Clicking the image hyperlink in the last cell works but clicking the row now redirects to the URL attached to the image hyperlink in the last cell.

How can I get it so clicking the row redirects to one URL, clicking the hyperlink in the last cell redirects to another?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$('#link-table tr td:not(:last-child)').click(function () {
        location.href = $(this).find('td a').attr('href');
    });
```

Your `$(this)` is the `'#link-table tr td:not(:last-child))'`, you can find the `tr` with
`var tr = $(this).closest('tr');` 
Then you can use `var tr` to do whatever you like

then find `'td a'` etc.

Comment: This was the correct solution. There is an extra bracket in there which was screwing things up a bit I think. Instead it should read

$('#link-table tr td:not(:last-child)').click

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to return:

```
$('#link-table tr').last().click(function () {
  return false;
});
```

Comment: You're selecting the last Row. He wants for all rows except the last td in the row.